# count key value in JSON and extract values

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have following JSONObject (not array, which I don't mind to convert). I am trying to do two things:

1. get the count of genre entry as "poetry" (count = 2).
2. get the key value of author name and genre:

   - authorName = malcolm
   - genreName = newsarticle
   - authorName = keats
   - genreName = poetry

```html
{ "AddressBook" :{

"Details" :{
"authorname" :{

"Author-malcolm":{
"genre" :"poetry"
}

"Author-keats":{
"genre" :"poetry"
}

}

}
}
}
```

Code which I tried:

```js
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException, ParseException {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("My path to JSON"));
    
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray arrayhere = new JSONArray();
        arrayhere.add(obj);
        System.out.println(arrayhere);             
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayhere.size(); i++) {
          JSONObject element = arrayhere.getJSONObject(i);//The method getJSONObject(int) is undefined for the type JSONArray
          String branchName = element.getString("genre");//The method getString(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject
          if(branchName.equals("poetry")) {
            count ++;
          }
        }
        System.out.println("Count f0r poetry genre=" + count);
    } 
     
}
```

I have looked at solutions all over. There is no question similar to this at stackoverflow. I am not sure if the procedure is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems here.

First, I'm not sure where you got that example JSON but you can't work with that. That's not even valid JSON Formatting.

Looks like you want something like this:

```
{
  AddressBook:
  [
    {
      authorname: "author-malcom",
      genre:"poetry"
    },
   {
      authorname: "author-keats",
      genre: "poetry"
   }
  ]
}
```

That's the structure you're trying to create in JSON.

So, you're parsing this in from a file into a `JSONObject` that has a key called `AddressBook` inside of it. That key points to an array of `JSONObjects` representing authors. Each of those objects will have a key called `genre`. You're trying to access the `genre` key and count on a condition.

What you did above was create attempt to create a `JSONObject` from an invalid string, and then add the entire `JSONObject` itself into the `JSONArray`. `JSONArray.add()` doesn't convert an object to an array, it literally adds it onto the array.

```
jsonObj => {"Name":"name1","Id":1000}
jsonArray.add(jsonObj)
jsonArray => [{"Name":"name1","Id":1000}]
```

That's what you did in your code above. You didn't **create** an array from a `JSONObject`, you **added** an object to the array.

Proper use is going to look like:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("path_to_file"));
JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) obj;

//access key AddressBook
JSONArray author_array = jobj.getJSONArray("AddressBook");

int poetry = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < author_array.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject author = (JSONObject) author_array.get(i);
  if(author.getString("genre").equals("poetry")) {
    poetry++;
  }
}
```

To summarize, you're problems come from a lack of understanding about JSON Formatting and how to access elements within a JSON Object.
Paste in the sample JSONObject I gave you above [here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). That site will let you visualize what you're working with.